# Decision theory - Example

Tags: decision-theory

Your wealth is $€14400$. If you have no accident, your wealth remains unchanged, but if you do, you need to pay $€4400$ to cover medical costs. If you have an accident, the insurance reimburses the medical costs but you need to pay a premium $p=€2300$ whether you have an accident or not. Your utility over wealth is $U(w) = {\sqrt w}$, the probability of an accident is $q$.

**(1) Suppose that you believe there is a probability $q=0.1$ of having an accident. What is the highest premium $p$ you would be willing to pay for the insurance?**

In this case the expected utility without insurance would be:

$E [U(N)]=q*U(14400-4400)+(1-q)*U(14400)$

$E [U(N)]=q*U(10000)+(1-q)*U(14400)$

$E [U(N)]=q*{\sqrt 10000}+(1-q)*{\sqrt 14400}$

$E [U(N)]=q*100+(1-q)*120$

$E [U(N)]=0.1*100+0.9*120$

$E [U(N)]=118$

In order to buy the insurance, expected utility with insurance (minus premium price) must be grater or equal the expected utility without insurance.
$E [U(I-premium)] ≥ E [U(N)]$.

So, $E [U(I-premium)] ≥ 118]$

Is it correct?

But I have also seen this this rule:

[image: rule]

$E [U(I)]=q*U(14400-premium)+(1-q)*U(14400-premium)≥0$

$E [U(I)]=0.1*U(14400-premium)+0.9*U(14400-premium)≥0$

And when I calculate it, I obtain that, with a probability of accident of $q=0.1$, the risk highest risk premium that a person would be willing to pay is exactly $€14400$, which is her/his entire wealth. This is a nonsense.

**How can I calculate the highest premium that a person would be willing to pay for the insurance?**

Any help is appreciated.

**(2) Suppose that you still believe $q=0.1$, but that your utility over wealth is now $U(w) = w$. What is the highest premium $p$ you would be willing to pay for the insurance? Explain intuitively how this premium compares with the one you found in the previous point.**

Here is the difference that this person is risk neutral, because of utility function $U(w) = w$, and in the first case we know that the person is risk averse, because of $U(w) = {\sqrt w}$ is a concave function. But how does the premium change? How can I calculate it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the insurance premium is $p$, and your wealth is $I$. You’ve found that your expected utility with insurance is just $U(I-p) = \sqrt{I-p}$.

You prefer to purchase insurance whenever the above quantity is higher than your expected utility without insurance, which you’ve found to be $118$. Thus, you are looking for the largest $p$ such that $$ \sqrt{14400 -p} \ge 118.$$

You can follow similar steps when $U(w)=w$.